# Rename a directory and subdirectory inside a directory having same name

Tags: rename

I have a directory called `Dual_Loop_PLL`.
Inside that I have 2 subdirectories: `agent` and `test`.
Inside `agent` I have a directory called `dl_pll_agent`, and inside `dl_pll_agent` I have `dl_pll_agent2`.
I want to rename `dl_pll_agent` and `dl_pll_agent2` to `dual_loop_pll_agent` and `dual_loop_pll_agent2` respectively.

I have used following command.

```
echo -e "Enter directory name you want to replace : "
read d1
echo "Enter directory name with which you want to replace : "
read d2
find  -type d -exec rename $d1 $d2 * {} +
```

but I am getting following error

```
rename: renaming ./Dual_Loop_PLL/agents/dl_pll_agent/dl_pll_agent2 to ./Dual_Loop_PLL/agents/dual_loop_pll_agent/dl_pll_agent2 failed: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What rename are you using: in `man rename` who is the author? What is the usage line of `rename --help`? (show by editing question)

Comment: `agents` or `agent`?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ./Dual_Loop_PLL/agents ./Dual_Loop_PLL/agents/dual_loop_pll_agent`

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `ls -l ./Dual_Loop_PLL/agents ./Dual_Loop_PLL/agents/dual_loop_pll_agent`?

If you will answer the above question then you will have the answer to your question.

Also read the manual for `rename`, and the section of the bash manual on quoting:
Always quote your variables e.g. `"$d1"`.

And I am not sure what you are doing with `rename`, you pass it: the evaluation of `$d1` and `$d2`, a list of all the files in the current directory, and a list of file found by `find`.